# kendo ui, update an array of objects

Tags: kendo-ui, observable

I am trying to simply update an object inside of an array, then update that array so that the data goes back to the view. After updating my object, and setting the array I am not seeing changes in the ui. Any thoughts?

sortTableColumn, is a click vent in the view, and thTitles is set using data-bind, I know that both are working because if I change the initial state of thTitles.sortClassName : "something", I will see that something in the ui.

```
 var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        sortTableColumn: function(e) {
            this.thTitles[1].sortClassName = "icon fa-sort-down";
            console.log(this.thTitles);
            var titles = this.thTitles;
            this.set("thTitles", titles);
        },
        thTitles: [
            { displayName: "Name", dataName: "name", sortDirection: 0, sortClassName:"" }, 
            { displayName: "Price", dataName: "price", sortDirection: 0, sortClassName: ""},
            { displayName: "Units", dataName: "unitsInStock", sortDirection: 0, sortClassName: ""}
        ],
});
 kendo.bind($("#tableSortable"), viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        sortTableColumn: function(e) {
                        this.get("thTitles")[1].set("sortClassName", "icon fa-sort-down");           

        },
        thTitles: [
            { displayName: "Name", dataName: "name", sortDirection: 0, sortClassName:"" }, 
            { displayName: "Price", dataName: "price", sortDirection: 0, sortClassName: ""},
            { displayName: "Units", dataName: "unitsInStock", sortDirection: 0, sortClassName: ""}
        ],
});
 kendo.bind($("#tableSortable"), viewModel);
```